# Move a window with custom borders using the mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, window, mousemove

I'm working on a C# project using WPF. In my MainWindow I just got rid of the default windows border and made an own border instead with a png file. I just set this as the background of the MainWindow.
Now I made some kinda tricky way to make my window move:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        mouseDown = true;
        lastX = (int)e.GetPosition(this).X;
        lastY = (int)e.GetPosition(this).Y;
    }

    private void Window_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (mouseDown) {
            int xDiff = (int)e.GetPosition(this).X - lastX;
            int yDiff = (int)e.GetPosition(this).Y - lastY;
            this.Left += xDiff;
            this.Top += yDiff;
        }
    }

    private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
```

Now this doesn't really work properly. This way the user can move the window at all clear spaces, even on Labels and TextBlocks. Is there a way to give the background or a border these kind of events? Or is there a better way to integrate borders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `made an own border instead with a png file` - It is strongly recommneded that you use WPF's built-in [Vector Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of bitmaps in WPF. bitmaps do not scale well and you may end up with a horribly pixelated UI on large screen resolutions

Comment: I'm having this application on just one resolution but thanks for the advice, I'll look into this!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, behavior is erratic when done manually but there's a fix for it.

This is the method in the framework that is specially for doing that :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dragmove(v=vs.110).aspx